# Metafizzy .isotope("layout") gives $elems is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

The jQuery Isotope plugin homepage explains that items containing images can result in overlapping in the isotope grid and that the [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) plugin can be used to fix this by calling the layout method once images are loaded like so:

```
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

The problem seems to be that layout requires an $elems parameter (at least w/ the masonry layout). So calling isotope.('layout') gives an error stating $elems is undefined. Is the example code incorrect? Should it call reLayout?

Sidebar, I was trying to solve overlapping of my images even though the `<img>` tags had a height attribute defined. It turns out, isotope does account for its size if *both* width and height are defined. I decided to use imagesLoaded to make sure it works either way.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful, but did you define your variable $container? `var $container = $('#your_ID');`

Comment: ALso, layout is for v2 of isotope, reLayout for v1.5

Comment: @Macsupport - Ahhh, you got it. I'm using v1 and hadn't noticed the site is now on v2. V2 was still in Beta when I started with it. Please add that as an answer so I can give you credit. Here is a jsfiddle for kicks: http://jsfiddle.net/htjdzhtz/47/. It's using v1. If you change `"layout"` to `"reLayout"` it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout is for v2 of isotope, reLayout for v1.5